# Ubuntu 14.04 SSH: Rejected From External Network

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, remote-connection

When trying to connect to my home server's SSH server, I receive the following:

```
ssh: connect to host host-here port 2222: Connection refused
```

I port forwarded 2222, to match up with 192.168.1.128:22, but it's still refusing my connections. No iptables, no ufw, nothing.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I've been trying for hours, and can't figure out the problem here. I **can** SSH in from a local machine (so, a computer within my house). Just not one outside of my home network.

Furthermore, -vvv...:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to nope.nope.nope.nope [nope.nope.nope.nope] port 2222.
debug1: connect to address nope.nope.nope.nope port 2222: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host nope.nope.nope.nope port 2222: Connection refused
```

I have BT's newest edition of BT Home Hub, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

how are you tring to connect?
i've tried my connection with

ssh name@server -p 222 -vvv

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server1.xxxxx.it [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 222.
debug1: Connection established.

then from your log seem like yuu ask for

ssh name@nope.nope.nope.nope

second your router have a public ip address on the outside interface?

Comment: This isn't an answer. But to answer your question at the end, yes, it does. I can connect to my web server through my home router.

Comment: i'm tring to help you ... ok now we know you have public ip adrress, let we know the command you use for connecting to your ssh server, there's a nope.nope.npoe on it? maybe my answer is for noob and you are not, but i don't know it, then don't worry